# Structure of Data with Mixed ANOVA in SPSS

Tags: spss, anova

I was told that I need a 3x2x2 mixed ANOVA. I am new relatively new to SPSS. I was wondering if someone could explain how to the data needs to be structured in SPSS. Meaning, how would I structure the rows and columns?

I have 3 trials of data (each trial containing hundreds of measurements) with 2 treatment conditions (0 Volts, and 15 Volts), and 2 different substrates used on which I grew cells (TCPS and PCSA) this is the in-between groups.

Please see this Infographic

[image: Infographic]

I originally ran multiple T-tests but was told to do ANOVA, here is the original plot with t-tests (it gives an idea of how I originally intended to look at the data).

[image: description]

As a side note- if anyone knows how to do this with python, I am also open to do it that way. Just based one what I have gathered, SPSS seems to be the only route.

Comment: If you are looking for statistical guidance, you should post this question on [Cross-Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). Is you're asking how to run an ANOVA on SPSS, you should start by googling [how to run two way anova in spss](https://www.google.co.il/search?safe=active&rlz=1C1CHWA_enIL638IL638&ei=r4e2WqG4CIn5wQL2yr64Dw&q=how+to+run+two+way+anova+in+spss&oq=how+to+run+two+way+anova+in+spss&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i7i30k1j0j0i8i30k1.20795.23266.0.24492.8.8.0.0.0.0.523.1445.0j3j2j5-1.6.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..2.6.1440...0i13k1j0i8i7i30k1j0i13i30k1j0i8i13i30k1.0.P__jZs2LGMY).

Comment: @eli-k I did extensively. I think my case was different due to the 3 trials. I finally did it in R.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone in the future: I was not able to do this in SPSS. However doing this in R is relatively simple. Put all data in one column of a CSV file (all 3 trials). For my case I had 3 additional columns of identifiers (Trial, Voltage, and Substrate). Open the file in R, store the data as a model, then run the ANOVA on the model with:

`model1 <- lm(NeuriteLength ~ Trial + Substrate*Voltage, data = D)
anova(model1)`